# Find instances within a column where consecutive rows are non zero?

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a pandas df column which contains 1's and 0's. Is there a way of finding all instances where in the column, a `1` appears n times in a row?

For example if n=4 then I'd get back rows 1 to 4 and 15 to 19, if it was 5 I would only get 15 to 19.

[Simple example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUBSd.png)

Thanks in advance!

---

Data input

```
l=[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
s=pd.Series(l)
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures. Copy and paste the dataframe instead -- https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC using `cumsum` create the `groupby` key

```
s1=s[s==0].groupby(s.ne(0).cumsum()).transform('size')
n=5

s[(s==0)&(s1==n)]
Out[753]: 
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    0
dtype: int64
```

Dput

```
l=[0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
s=pd.Series(l)
```